# How to remove the `let` reassignment in a `for` block

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to remove the `let` reassignment in the below function within a for block scope.
I want to accumulate the value within the `block scope of for loop` but not to access a closure or global variable(`totalValue`) which is outside of `for` loop block scope.
Because it makes the code more readable and maintainable for bigger functions.

I am looking for any alternate way which removes the `let re-assignment pattern`  as shown below to acheive the same functionality.

```js
function howToRemoveLetReassignmentForTheBelowScenario(target: number) {
  let totalValue: number = 0;
  for (
    let i = 0;
    i < target; // iteration is happening based on a condition where both variables are of number type. Wanted to highlight the point that there is no array.
    i++
  ) {
    const calculatedValueForEachIteration: number = i + Math.random()
    totalValue += calculatedValueForEachIteration; // `let` re-assignmnet hapening here.
  }
  return totalValue
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=81&pln=3&pc=4#code/PQKhCgAIUhZBPSBzA9gQwDYC5JRgSUjQFtIAXAJ3gEsA7JclSCgU2JQDcXyALbgAwwsy-ZizQBnCdSS1iLWmUh1e3AEYsMKAO6QAZgFdaAYzLUUtSNupkeKtPpQVIarcYDWAOlzRIhbWiKLAAmjETGxgbEBhhoZNy23ByYBtzWtiqJkPyuKB6QEsYoAA7cKHqOzlolomoGSrQoSmRMaBEsUkSQyRTUaK4sABT8LWSYAGopLPwAlFZ2xjzKEpAo9dLBZRX8ek6i1cUubu4FRaWeeJAAQizGaAYS3DaQxGjuCXyQRZsvTtysaGC-SERFooVedDGdGB3F2zjUMiQLGchhMZgsEguvjwwHA4FRpnMlh4OgAKigAEpsTgsAAywipkmksnkigAYk5SXwblptABlYwKNC9FCDMYUJFkHC0KIaChzADeUEgQmaTQmU2lsuRkAAvJAAAwAbmVcMgg2VkBVwmUesNJqtVuokAAPORhZKHY7qABqH3KxWWr4YpR3DCRWLxYKTDCpDkUACibR4+HiFDiRK1xDldudPrgcR4nnTYJQxEGMyDow1se4Pv1YYjcRCMbjTiTi1TyIzFiNkGAwGyqtErAAtEyZHJaDaeGhSrQ6Aw+KwsZAAL7K1hkAwUSzVjCtljgNdAA)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you define totalValue in the `for` loop scope, you cannot access it in the function scope (unless you define it as var)

Comment: Even better use `.reduce()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @y2bd, @trash_dev : I tried to use reduce, but we cannot use reduce because there is no array in the function.
Iterations are happening based on a condition `i < target` where both are `number` type.

Comment: @sashank you can create an array based on `target` with `[...Array(target).keys()]` and then use `reduce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array(n)` you can use `reduce`:

```js
const target = 10;
const totalValue = [...Array(target).keys()]
  .reduce((acc, value) =>
    acc += (value + Math.random())
  );
  
 console.log(totalValue);
```

Comment: Thank you. Just curios to know can we solve this using recursion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way using "for" loop. How do we return the variable out of for loop if the variable scope is only within for loop? "for" is not a function that returns something.

Comment: it doesn't have to be `for` loop. I am looking for any alternate solution which removes `let re-assignement pattern` which is a better readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'let reassignment pattern'. Your options are either a loop (`for`, `while`) or using array reduce as in other answers. My opinion is that the `for` loop is more readable than creating an array and using array reduce. I don't know if this is just because I am relatively new to JavaScript. You're still going to need to run the same code in a loop to calculate the subtotal (`subTotal += newValue`). I feel that, as a reader, it is quite apparent what is happening in your code - the function is written well, defining variables at the right scope, and performing a single, simple task). It just needs a name that describes the functionality to make it immediately apparent to the user.

Another possible consideration is that (from a few tests with a target of 1000), a `for` loop comes in at 0.02ms and creating an array and then performing an array reduce takes between 0.14ms and 0.7ms. While 0.7ms is still small, it seems like a sacrifice to gain little readability.

If you're really concerned about readability, I would recommend using a class with a self-explanatory name and clear method names. This makes the functionality really understandable when a reader looks at it:

```
class Accumulator {
    #subtotal = 0;
    add(n: number) {
        this.#subtotal += n;
    }
    getTotal() {
        return this.#subtotal;
    }
}

function sumConsecutiveNumbers(from: number, to: number) {
    let accumulator = new Accumulator();
    for (let i=from; i <= to; i++) accumulator.add(i);
    return accumulator.getTotal();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail.I beleive in 2021 with 5G network and http 2.0, readability and maintainability of code is more important than performance.
Why I dont like the `let re-assignment pattern` is imagine a function which is 100 lines long. If a developer writes multiple if conditions within this function and reassigns the value of the let variable in each of the if condition. It is just hard(takes more time to understand)  for other develoeprs to understand what is happening within the function.

Comment: @sashank I agree that speed isn’t much of a concern with most modern apps. If a function is too long and complex and is doing multiple things to the same variable you should try and split it out (a function should only do one thing and its name should make the purpose clear). It may be that you should define more variables (e.g if adding several people’s ages and favourite numbers and then getting an overall total, you may wish to calculate ‘ageSum’, ‘favNumSum’, then ‘totalSum + ageSum + favNumSum’ to keep it clear what’s what. If function/variable names/usage is good then don’t worry

Comment: Take a look at the following as it’s great for best practices in terms of readability: https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript. The tricky thing is understanding what code is trying to do so just ensure that is clear, modern IDEs make following variables throughout a long piece of code straight forward. In a complex example there are probably other changes to be made if it isn’t readable, in this basic example above I would definitely stick with what you have!

Comment: I totally agree with your point on creating SRP(single responsibility functions) to improve readability and maintainability. Thanks for sharing th egithub link, it is usefull.